# What does Shotwell do when I move photos inside the photo directory

Tags: directory, shotwell, photo-management

I have enabled 'Watch library directory for new files' and imported many photos with the settings `<Lib>/<year>/<month>/<day>/<..>`.

I have since decided to move to `<Lib>/<year>/<month>/<..>` and would now like to clean up the old folders.

Can I simply move the files into the `month` folder and Shotwell will pick it up and fix it?